# SQLiteで構造体リストをそのままinsertしたい

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity2d

Unityで開発を行っております。

```
create table hoge_view( hoge_id1 integer, hoge_id2 integer, hoge_id3 integer, hoge_id4 integer, hoge_id5 integer );
```

といったテーブルを作成しました。
こちらのテーブルに下記の構造体リストの値をインサートしたいと考えております。

```
public class HogeData
{
    public List<HogeValue>  value;
}

[Serializable]
public class HogeValue
{
    public int  hoge_id1;
    public int  hoge_id2;
    public int  hoge_id3;
    public int  hoge_id4;
    public int  hoge_id5;
}
```

こちらリスト数が4万ほどになる場合があり、insertコマンドをその分呼び出すのに大変時間が掛かります。
リストをそのままinsertすることは可能なのでしょうか

何かアドバイスいただけたらと思います。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 確認ですがこのデータをデータベースに格納してクエリ等を行うのでしょうか？ そういうデータ構造には見えないため気になりました。もしも単なるストレージ代わりに使うのであれば、オーバーヘッドが大きすぎるように思います。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[How to bulk insert into SQLITE database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36778304/9014308) あるいはこちらとか。[6.1 トランザクションと速度](https://qiita.com/koshian2/items/63938474001c510d0b15#61-%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B6%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A8%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6)

Answer (score 3):

[一括挿入](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/bulk-insert)によると

> SQLite には、データを一括挿入するための特別な方法はありません。 データの挿入または更新時に最適なパフォーマンスを得るには、以下を行ってください。
>
> - トランザクションの使用。
> - 同じパラメーター化コマンドの再利用。 後続の実行で、最初の実行のコンパイルを再利用します。

と案内されています。

マシン環境が異なるので所要時間が異なりますが、

- takemori_kondoさんのコード： 402ms
- 一括挿入： 230ms
- 一括挿入から`tran`をコメントアウト： 243,755ms

と愚直にループしてもかなり高速になります。

```
#if false
    foreach (var group in list.Select((hv, i) => (hv, i)).GroupBy(x => x.i / 1000))
    {
        using var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        var values = String.Join(", ", group.Select(x => $"({x.hv.hoge_id1}, {x.hv.hoge_id2}, {x.hv.hoge_id3}, {x.hv.hoge_id4}, {x.hv.hoge_id5})"));
        cmd.CommandText = $"insert into hoge_view values {values};";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
#else
    using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into hoge_view values ($hoge_id1, $hoge_id2, $hoge_id3, $hoge_id4, $hoge_id5);";
        var hoge_id1 = cmd.CreateParameter(); hoge_id1.ParameterName = nameof(hoge_id1); cmd.Parameters.Add(hoge_id1);
        var hoge_id2 = cmd.CreateParameter(); hoge_id2.ParameterName = nameof(hoge_id2); cmd.Parameters.Add(hoge_id2);
        var hoge_id3 = cmd.CreateParameter(); hoge_id3.ParameterName = nameof(hoge_id3); cmd.Parameters.Add(hoge_id3);
        var hoge_id4 = cmd.CreateParameter(); hoge_id4.ParameterName = nameof(hoge_id4); cmd.Parameters.Add(hoge_id4);
        var hoge_id5 = cmd.CreateParameter(); hoge_id5.ParameterName = nameof(hoge_id5); cmd.Parameters.Add(hoge_id5);
        foreach (var hv in list)
        {
            hoge_id1.Value = hv.hoge_id1;
            hoge_id2.Value = hv.hoge_id2;
            hoge_id3.Value = hv.hoge_id3;
            hoge_id4.Value = hv.hoge_id4;
            hoge_id5.Value = hv.hoge_id5;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        tran.Commit();
    }
#endif
```

Comment: 理屈的にはforeachの前にcmd.Prepare();やるべきかと思いましたが、私の環境では全く早くなりませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

自分の環境で計測してみましたが、SQLiteをSSDの環境で実行しても、
1Insert当たり20~30ms程度かかるようです。
問題はSQLの発行回数なので、例えば、

insert into hoge_view values(...),(...)

形式にすれば、SQL発行回数を減らせます。
SQLiteでは40000value句そのまま対応できているみたいなので、１SQLで行けるようです。
ただし、Value句が多くなりすぎると異常に時間がかかり始めるようなので、
1000value句程度で分割すると最も早く処理できます。

下記サンプルを実行したところ、1.5秒程度でした。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using Dapper;

...

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var length = 40000;
            var list = new List<HogeValue>();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                var val = new HogeValue()
                {
                    hoge_id1 = i * 10 + 1,
                    hoge_id2 = i * 10 + 2,
                    hoge_id3 = i * 10 + 3,
                    hoge_id4 = i * 10 + 4,
                    hoge_id5 = i * 10 + 5,
                };
                list.Add(val);
            }

            var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=sqlitedb.db;"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn.Query("drop table hoge_view;");
                conn.Query("create table hoge_view( hoge_id1 integer, hoge_id2 integer, hoge_id3 integer, hoge_id4 integer, hoge_id5 integer );");                
                sw.Start();
                var sqlpart1 = "insert into hoge_view values";
                var sql = sqlpart1;
                var counter = 0;
                foreach (var i in list)
                {
                    counter++;
                    sql += $@"({i.hoge_id1}, {i.hoge_id2}, {i.hoge_id3}, {i.hoge_id4}, {i.hoge_id5}),";
                    if (1000 <= counter)
                    {
                        sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 1);
                        conn.Query(sql);
                        counter = 0;
                        sql = sqlpart1;
                    }
                }
                if (counter != 0)
                {
                    sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 1);
                    conn.Query(sql);
                    counter = 0;
                }
                
            }
            var ms = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine($"{ms} ms, done!");
            Console.WriteLine("end");
        }
```